# How to update a column with specific data for each row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to update one database containing NBA players by linking their `uid` from another database. How would I go about linking each players specific `UID` to their unique player name in this table? Would I be using an 
`UPDATE` or an `INSERT INTO` query?  I understand how to update regularly, I'm just stuck on the part of having the right players id with their name. (I couldn't manually insert their `uid` as there as 500+ players)

Comment: provide sample datas from these tables and show us the expected output. we would like to know what columns are in what table.

Comment: `INSERT INTO` is for creating new rows, `UPDATE` is for modifying existing rows.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use `UPDATE` with `JOIN` to copy values from one table to related rows in another table.